# Fade text near end of div?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fade the text horizontally near the end of the div using the CSS.

For example like this:

[image]

Comment: Gradient overlay, image overlay, browser-specific filters...

Comment: I vote for an image overlay unless browser is specified

Comment: What about using `text-overflow:ellipsis` instead?

Comment: Relevant thread on UX SE: **[Studies or experience on using faded text to indicate more content?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20265/studies-or-experience-on-using-faded-text-to-indicate-more-content)**. Relevant tutorial from D. Walsh: **[Elegant Overflow with CSS Ellipsis](http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS gradients and `rgba` will do the job for this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KTAGm/)

[**Extended Text Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/KTAGm/2/) (Updated)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;    
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.6)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    top: 0;
```

}

> Note: I've stripped off cross-browser CSS gradient code, you can get
>   it from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

About the `rgba()` it's introduced recently in CSS3 spec, where I hope you know what RGB stands for and `a` stands for alpha, so instead of using `HEX` I am using `RGBA` and am just playing with the alpha part here

Comment: I think you should update it to be Webkit compatible; those are some popular browsers

Comment: Here we go, -2 and Explosion Pills, it's just that I didn't wanted to dump a whole lot of code here, but I'll just make a demo out of it

Comment: You can't just add `-webkit-linear-gradient` to make this work though; the `135deg` is not quite compatible, so it requires additional changes.  Frankly I would make the webkit-compatible version *first*

Comment: @ExplosionPills I know, actually I generate gradient codes from colorzilla and as you know it saves the last used in session, it saved diagonal which I used previously for my project as the default so changed it, thanks for drawing my attention to it

Answer (score 4):

Skipping IE9-, which may require an image or SVG, you can add a `position: absolute` div that covers the full width and has a partially-transparent gradient that fades to white.  This div must be contained by the element you want to cover, which must be `position: relative`.

http://jsfiddle.net/JcPAT/

Answer (score 2):

Not really cross browser friendly but you can use something like:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
mask-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
```

Comment: Which browsers currently support either version?

Comment: so, it's a webkit feature that got acknowledged by W3C? :-)