# How to fade a div's content out at the end of the element?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with stuff in it on a page with a background gradient.
Now towards the right, I would like to fade that `div` out to the background:

[image]

I have tried using background gradients, but those are behind the text. Basically what I would need was a `foreground` property which I could fill with another gradient.

How can I achieve this without needing to use `canvas` and JavaScript?

Comment: I've answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722975/fade-text-near-end-of-div

Comment: @Mr.Alien Wouldn't the gradient be a problem with your method?

Comment: If you've a background gradient already and you are using my gradient than yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a transparent .png image and applying it as a background on top of the div with text by creating a class with absolute positioning.

```
.transparent {background: url("xxxxxx.png") repeat-y 0 0 transparent; position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:1;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This div should be on top of the div with the text of course!

Comment: Yes. It should be above the text. - @rxt

Answer (score 0):

A transparent (rgba) gradient in a separate DIV positioned absolutely on top of the original div should do the trick.

Caveat: Absolute positioning may not be feasible, depeding on your layout.