# CSS faded section at top of scrolling div

Tags: html, css

I want to add a faded section to the top of my DIV such that, when a user scrolls, the content gradually fades out.  I have set up some CSS that achieves this but has one issue.. The faded section scrolls with the content rather than staying fixed in place.

How can I fix this? Do I need help from jQuery or is it possible using CSS and will this work in anything bar CSS3 compatible browsers? (I know I dont have correct vendor prefixes on my `linear-gradient`s yet)

Here is my code so far and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hP3wu/):

```css
.fadedScroller {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.fadedScroller:after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(251,251,251,1) 0%,rgba(251,251,251,0) 100%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Update**

I have updated [my fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hP3wu/11/) to point out that using `position: fixed` doesnt actually work as the faded section then appears above the containing div not fixed to the top.

Comment: I've had a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16396951/522479

Comment: To your update, what the hell is `display:fixed`? ;) I think you mean `position:fixed`?!

Comment: @yckart Oh yeah - typo, updated

Comment: @Chris `position:fixed` cannot be relative to anything, except the browser-window!

Comment: would you be open to using JQuery? or just pure CSS?

Comment: @yckart I know, I was writing it to inform some of the people who wrote answers.

Comment: @pandavenger Yes I am, if it is not possible using CSS only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creating a second div to hold the gradient and shifting it over the the content div works.
I know this is kind of dirty and not very intuitive to write, but it works.

Demo:

```css
.fadedScroller {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.fadedScroller_fade {
  content: '';
  margin-top: -100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(251, 251, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(251, 251, 251, 0) 100%);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadedScroller">
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
    awesome stuff here<br />
</div>
<div class="fadedScroller_fade"></div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/hP3wu/12/

Comment: +1 This is basically the same conclusion I came to: http://fiddle.jshell.net/hP3wu/15/ - One drawback is that you can't click on the top part of the scrollbar (including arrow up) because the overlay is in the way =/

Comment: Another hackish workaround could be http://fiddle.jshell.net/hP3wu/18/ - make space for the scrollbar, and use overflow: scroll so it always appears. Still bad, because width of scrollbar is unknown...

Comment: I wrote a solution using JQuery, but this is probably the best solution without scripts.

Comment: actually you can use :before to get this done cleaner :)

Comment: Add `pointer-events: none; ` to .fadedScroller_fade and you can click/scroll the contents while over the faded area.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`:

```
.fadedScroller:after {
    content:'';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(251, 251, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(251, 251, 251, 0) 100%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hP3wu/4/

**Update1**

https://jsfiddle.net/hP3wu/7/

**Update2**

https://jsfiddle.net/hP3wu/9/

Comment: Fading effect is extremely weakened (almost unnoticeable) for me in the fiddle. (FF21/Linux3.8.12)

Comment: @Cobra_Fast That is because `position:absolute` is contained in `position:relative` so it is not at `top:0` of your window. So, adjust the height to e.g. `40px` :)

Comment: After giving it `position: fixed;` the position is no longer relative to `.fadedScroller` - http://fiddle.jshell.net/hP3wu/6/

Comment: Still doesn't fully fade out. I'd expect it to fade to be completely invisible (since the top of the gradient has an alpha of `1`).

Comment: That works so long as `.fadedScroller` is at the top of the window, it is not.  As it happens its positioned in the middle of the page so this doesnt work

Comment: @Cobra_Fast `body` has a padding by default, so reset padding to 0, or set your ``top` to the default `padding`-value. http://fiddle.jshell.net/hP3wu/9/

Comment: If `.fadedScroller:after` is relative to origin instead of any parent element, it's gonna be a pain to use for anything else than fading out the entire page...

Comment: @Cobra_Fast `position:fixed` cannot be relative to anything, except the browser-window!

Comment: Which is what I meant by "origin".

Answer (score 1):

This is a **huge** workaround solution, so apologies, but this is the only way I could think of: http://fiddle.jshell.net/hP3wu/17/

So first I made another `div` with `class="after"` because I cannot select the `:after` pseudo-element with JQuery

Then I made the `div.after` reposition itself each time a scroll occurs in the `.fadedScrollbar` `div` with

```
$(".fadedScroller").scroll(function () {
    $(".fadedScroller .after").css("top", $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: +1 This is likely the best working solution, except for mobile devices because they don't fire the scroll event until the scrolling has stopped.

Comment: @xec thanks, I edited it, and feel free to add anything you feel should be there.

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ne1baj4e/1/ This is a my modification of yckart's solution, which reduces the fade when the div is scrolled to the top. It simply adds this bit of Javascript/JQuery:

```
const FADE_HEIGHT = 40;
let oldStyle = $(`<style>.fadedScroller:after {top: -${FADE_HEIGHT}px;}</style>`).appendTo("head");

$(".fadedScroller").scroll(() => {
  let offset = Math.min($(".fadedScroller").scrollTop() - FADE_HEIGHT, 0);

  oldStyle.remove();

  oldStyle = $(`<style>.fadedScroller:after {top: ${offset}px;}</style>`).appendTo("head");
});
```

Fading at the bottom of a div is similar except you'll need to calculate the offset as

```
$(".fadedScroller")[0].scrollHeight - $(".fadedScroller")[0].clientHeight - $(".fadedScroller")[0].scrollTop
```